# sudo takes too long to start

Tags: fedora, sudo

I'm using Fedora 23, the same problem was on Fedora 22. Sudo takes ~20 seconds to start, it doing something for ~20 seconds then asks password.

Reboot solves this problem for a while. After a few hours the problem appear again.

Here is peace of strace output

```
 0.000022 write(7, "\1", 1)         = 1
 0.000038 rt_sigreturn({mask=[INT QUIT]}) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
 0.000026 --- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
 0.000012 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
25.025434 sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1\204\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 144}, {"\177\0\0\0type='signal',sender='net.re"..., 132}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 276
 0.000378 sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1\246\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 144}, {"\241\0\0\0type='signal',sender='org.fr"..., 166}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 310
 0.000176 write(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
 0.000109 close(11)                 = 0
 0.000121 close(12)                 = 0
 0.000090 getuid()                  = 1000
```

You can see that sendmsg takes too much time.

Can someone help me with this? I don't want to reboot my laptop every time this happen.

```
uname -a
Linux c0rp 4.4.9-300.fc23.x86_64
```

Link to strace http://pastebin.com/n5GWi9G1

Here is output from `strace -f -v -s300 -o log sudo`

```
8204  poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLIN}])
8204  read(11, "AGREE_UNIX_FD\r\n", 2048) = 15
8204  poll([{fd=11, events=POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLOUT}])
8204  sendto(11, "BEGIN\r\n", 7, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 7
8204  poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLOUT}])
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0n\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\6\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.fr
eedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\5\0\0\0Hello\0\0\0", 128}, {"", 0}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 128
8204  poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLIN}])
8204  recvmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\2\1\1\v\0\0\0\1\0\0\0=\0\0\0\6\1s\0\6\0\0\0:1.491\0\0\5\1u\0\1\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0\7\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0:1
.491\0l\4\1\1\v\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\215\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\f\0\0\0NameAcquired\0\0\0\0\6\1s\0\6\0\0\0:1.491\0\0\10\
1g\0\1s\0\0\7\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0:1.491\0", 2048}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 262
8204  recvmsg(11, 0x7ffec28d88e0, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
8204  eventfd2(0, EFD_CLOEXEC|EFD_NONBLOCK) = 12
8204  write(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)  = 8
8204  fstat(11, {st_dev=makedev(0, 8), st_ino=3014822, st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=0, st_mtime=0, st_ctime=0})
 = 0
8204  fcntl(11, F_GETFL)                = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
8204  write(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)  = 8
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1\204\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\6\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\10\0\0\0AddMatch\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0", 144}, {"\177\0\0\0type='signal',sender='net.reactivated.Fprint',path='/net/reactivated/Fprint/Manager',interface='net.reactivated.Fprint.Manager'\0", 132}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 276
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1\246\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\6\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\10\0\0\0AddMatch\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0", 144}, {"\241\0\0\0type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',path='/org/freedesktop/DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',arg0='net.reactivated.Fprint'\0", 166}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 310
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\0\1\33\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\6\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\f\0\0\0GetNameOwner\0\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0", 144}, {"\26\0\0\0net.reactivated.Fprint\0", 27}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 171
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\203\0\0\0\1\1o\0\37\0\0\0/net/reactivated/Fprint/Manager\0\6\1s\0\26\0\0\0net.reactivated.Fprint\0\0\2\1s\0\36\0\0\0net.reactivated.Fprint.Manager\0\0\3\1s\0\n\0\0\0GetDevices\0\0\0\0\0\0", 152}, {"", 0}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 152
8204  poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLIN}])
8204  recvmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\2\1\1\v\0\0\0\3\0\0\0=\0\0\0\6\1s\0\6\0\0\0:1.491\0\0\5\1u\0\4\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0\7\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0:1.413\0", 2048}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 91
8204  write(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)  = 8
8204  recvmsg(11, 0x7ffec28d8730, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
8204  poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
8204  --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
8204  restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>) = 0
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1\204\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\6\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\v\0\0\0RemoveMatch\0\0\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0", 144}, {"\177\0\0\0type='signal',sender='net.reactivated.Fprint',path='/net/reactivated/Fprint/Manager',interface='net.reactivated.Fprint.Manager'\0", 132}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 276
8204  sendmsg(11, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1\246\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\6\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0org.freedesktop.DBus\0\0\0\0\3\1s\0\v\0\0\0RemoveMatch\0\0\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0", 144}, {"\241\0\0\0type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',path='/org/freedesktop/DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',arg0='net.reactivated.Fprint'\0", 166}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 310
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
#initgroups: files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname mymachines

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Comment: Please provide full strace output, if necessary, post it to pastebin.

Comment: still insufficient; poll call timeouts then recvmsg plays with something that comes from freedesktop code? `strace -f -v -s300 -o log sudo ...` will give the best info.

Comment: Check that your syslog daemon is working correctly; 
For example, does logger 'Hello world' return within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: look for the other end of fd=11...

Comment: @malyy it works very fast

Comment: @siblynx updated

Comment: Are you using LDAP, Kerberos or any other kind of authentication method? Also, check your full qualified domain. I have seen this bug happening when your network has a problem.

Comment: So judging by `connect(11, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 29) = 0` - you probably got problems with dbus, possibly dbus daemon is not running or malfunction.

Comment: please add the contents of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to your question

Comment: @cas added to question

Comment: thanks for reminding me, i meant to post my answer hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

The full strace in your pastebin link shows that sudo is trying to open `libnss-sss.so.2`:

```
open("/lib64/libnss_sss.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
```

That's an NSS module for [SSSD - System Security Services Daemon](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/), which manages access to various remote authentication services.

Check that the SSSD is installed and running.  If it is, then try following the [instructions](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/HOWTO_Troubleshoot_SUDO) on that site for debugging `sudo` issues.

If it isn't then either find out why and fix it or (if you don't want/need `sss`) just edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and comment out or delete `sss` from all the services that are configured to use it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already reboot my laptop, I will check it when this happen again and let you know.

Comment: I removed all `sss` but it is still long pause befora asking password. Also I can't restart sssd, it is saying: `Job for sssd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sssd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`